# asp.net page with iframe with youtube video sometimes requires refresh

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

I have an asp.net page with an iframe in it that shows a youtube video.  I have buttons that use the youtube api to control the video.  I'm finding that often the video doesn't show up, and I have to do a view-refresh to make it work.  This problem is limited to Internet Explorer, I believe that Google chrome does not have the same problem.
I've been told not to use iframes at all by a tech support person at the server company that hosts my site.  They say people are moving away from iframes, and that I should use other methods of embedding youtube videos.
I could certainly do that, but youtube recommends using iframes, because they are more flexible.
If I could make the 'refresh' problem predictable, I would submit it to Microsoft, but I can't figure out why it happens sometimes, but not other times.
I could also force a refresh.
My question is, does anyone have a clue why this bug is happening.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot with IFRAME content.  I believe it's to do with the way that Internet Explorer caches stuff, but to be perfectly honest, I'm not sure on the details.

What I can share is an old trick we used to use with dialog boxes.

Say your src attribute is `"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wL7RHoDnxs"`

You can bang an extra parameter onto that GET string, like:-

```
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wL7RHoDnxs&doesntmatter=203933"
```

See the extra `doesntmatter` parameter there?  The value is random, or based on a timestamp.  Your choice.  The trick is to give a different URL to IE each time.  This'll stop it from trying to use a cache for your IFRAME content.

Comment: turns out the api sample code doesnt' work right with IE.  To make it work, the part that creates the player has to be in the jquery document-ready event (if you are using jquery)